# Xamarin Forms: How to reduce height of Tabs using TabbedPageRenderer

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I am developing Tabs using custom `TabbedPageRenderer`. I need to reduce the height of Tabs. Tabs are showing huge margin at bottom & top side.
See below my code
*MyTabbedPageRenderer.cs*

```
    [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyTabbedPage), typeof(MyTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace TabbedApp.Droid
{
    public class MyTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
    {
        protected override void SetTabIcon(TabLayout.Tab tab, FileImageSource icon)
        {
            base.SetTabIcon(tab, icon);
            tab.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.CustomTabLayout);           
            var imageview = tab.CustomView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.icon);
            var tv = tab.CustomView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv);
            tv.SetText(tab.Text, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
            imageview.SetBackgroundDrawable(tab.Icon);

        }
    }
}
```

*CustomTabLayout.axml*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="hello"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="13dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

*MainPage & MyTabbedPage*

```
public partial class MainPage : MyTabbedPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

public class MyTabbedPage : TabbedPage
    {

    }
```

*Main.xaml*

```
 <MyTabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="TabbedApp.MainPage"        
                 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabbedApp">
         <local:DairyTabPage  Icon="dairy" HeightRequest="10" WidthRequest="10" ></local:DairyTabPage>
         <local:MykidTab   Icon="kid" ></local:MykidTab>
         <local:Events   Icon="events"></local:Events>
         <local:About  Icon="about"></local:About>
    </MyTabbedPage>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add height to linearlayout

Comment: As I know height and width of `LinearLayout` is very close to the `Imageview` & `Textview`. Size of tabs is irrespective to `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Tab layout as per standard it is `56dp` so you can add it directly to the CustomTabLayout.axml Linear tag and check

Comment: @Amjad I didn't get you. are telling me to add `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` in the CustomTabLayout.axml file if yes I am not using TabLayout from axml.

Comment: No change this line  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="56dp"`

Comment: After changing height to 56dp top margin reduced to almost 80% but bottom margin is still the same.And it reduced height of tab almost 10%

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168185/discussion-between-amjad-khan-and-priyanka-agrawal).

Answer (score 0):

try this for layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="hello" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Programmatically you can try this

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        FormsAppCompatActivity.TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.tabs;
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        RegisterIoC();
        LoadApplication(new App());
        setupTabIcons();
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() 
    {
        var tabLayout = (TabLayout) FindViewById(Resource.Id.tabs);
        if(tabLayout != null)
        {
            TextView tabOne = (TextView)LayoutInflater.From(this).Inflate(Resource.Layout.tab, null);
            tabOne.Text = "ONE";
            tabOne.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, Resource.Drawable.ic_tab_todo, 0, 0);
            tabLayout.GetTabAt(0).SetCustomView(tabOne);

            TextView tabTwo = (TextView)LayoutInflater.From(this).Inflate(Resource.Layout.tab, null);
            tabTwo.Text = "TWO";
            tabTwo.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, Resource.Drawable.ic_tab_pending, 0, 0);
            tabLayout.GetTabAt(1).SetCustomView(tabTwo);

            TextView tabThree = (TextView)LayoutInflater.From(this).Inflate(Resource.Layout.tab, null);
            tabThree.Text = "THREE";
            tabThree.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, Resource.Drawable.ic_tab_done, 0, 0);
            tabLayout.GetTabAt(2).SetCustomView(tabThree);
        }
```

Comment: See my updated question where I have attached latest tab screenshot. I wonder if I get reduced top & bottom margin some more.

Comment: see my updated question, I am not able to reduce the height of tabs

Comment: Now u can refer

Comment: what is `Resource.Id.tabs` & `Resource.Layout.tab`, is it separate layout? If yes than first line of `setupTabIcons()` method how will be working?